# How to get big response body Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Tell me what the problem is, and how to solve it. I need to get a response array json format. On the server, the response is formed in about 30 minutes, collects an array of 150K elements. Then it comes to dispatch, and hangs on hold for more than 24 hours. But even after such a long time, the answer does not come. There are no errors on the server. If you take 10K, then the answer comes without problems. I tried to save the answer to a TXT file, its size is +-35MB, and contains 35K stock.

This is how I execute the request:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URLs.sayt + "/" + URLs.api + "/hs/CLIENTS/LIST/")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .timeout(0)
                    .userAgent(URLs.getUserAgentMobile())
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
                    .header("Accept-Language", "*")
                    .header("mode", "tobase")
                    .execute();
            if(response != null){
                ArrayList<Client> clients = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), new TypeToken<List<Client>>() {}.getType());
                for (Client client:clients){
                    sqLiteWork.AddToClient(client);
                }
            }
```

Here is an example of an element from the json array:

```
{"id": "9812d904-2d8a-11e8-80bb-a45d36c35311", "name": "Afaq", "code": "", "isGroup": false, "parent": "null", "address": "", "phone": "+994(12) 436 71 88", "phoneMore": "+994(50)2409696", "phoneHome": "", "debt": 0 }
```

Comment: and why you are using jsoup as http client?

Comment: It seems to me, or so it is, I asked how to get and what could be the problem, and not what is better to use.

Comment: I do not understand much about what you cannot do.  What is the problem you are experiencing?  The question reads like your **HTTP Server** java program is taking 24 hours to compute an answer.  Is it taking 24 hours for your **HTTP Server** to compute the answer to a client request?  Is that it?  If it takes so long, perhaps you should pre-compute the answer so it is ready for a download when your client is making requests.  Do you own and control the software in the **HTTP Server**?  If you do, making a client wait 24 hours for a response sounds like a mistake that you have to change first.

Comment: Probably I put it badly. I wrote the server side it WORKS CORRECT. The response is formed in 30 minutes. And sent to the client. But the client waits or processes the response for more than 24 hours and still does not receive it. I tried to open it through the browser, everything works. I tried to reduce the array to 10k elements, it still works. But with a large array of 150k items, the client waits or processes the response endlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution to my question. I've tried both okhttp and httpurlconnection. Apparently, the android client itself does not support such a large string response in the body. Maybe it would be a solution via a file. But this is not a solution when you need actual data. Therefore, I made a response from the server for 10K elements. Full loading of 150K elements takes 2 hours.

Please note, I'm talking up-to-date data, if 2 hours is a long time, then online mode is also supported in my application.

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(URLs.sayt + "/" + URLs.api + "/hs/CLIENTS/LIST/")
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .timeout(0)
                    .userAgent(URLs.getUserAgentMobile())
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
                    .header("Accept-Language", "*")
                    .header("mode", "tobase");

            Connection.Response response = connection.execute();
            ArrayList<Client> clients = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), new TypeToken<List<Client>>() {}.getType());
            Client last = null;
            for (Client client:clients){
                last = client;
                sqLiteWork.AddToClient(client);
            }

            while (clients.size() > 0){
                response = connection.header("last", last.id).execute();
                clients = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), new TypeToken<List<Client>>() {}.getType());
                for (Client client:clients){
                    last = client;
                    sqLiteWork.AddToClient(client);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The last part of your code is making a connection back to the server for each element in your `ArrayList clients`.  This part makes absolutely no sense to me.  The last while loop in your code is making one connection for each element in the `clients ArrayList`.  You have clearly stated that this `ArrayList` is to have either 10,000 or 150,000 elements in it.  This does mean you would be making 150,000 connections back to your server.  I am surprised this code isn't taking you 2 weeks!

Comment: It seems you have not read my code carefully. There is a line in the loop:

`response = connection.header("last", last.id).execute();`

And the `last.id` after each request is different. Therefore, the connection is made only 15 times. 
Take a closer look at the code.

Comment: Yes, I have.  I looked at it for quite some time this morning.  Over and over.

Comment: Speaking frankly - you need to reevaluate where your 30 minutes or 24 hours are going.  You do something that involves a **Database** update, which nobody here can help you with because the DB method is not posted, and you also have additional queries to the server.  Why don't you make some effort to print out the time-stamp when these loops are running so you can identify exactly what is taking so long.  I mean, clearly downloading one set of data should not, but executing the same query over and over again should.  **Print out `System.currentTimeMillis()`** and repost your question with that

Comment: I measured, there are no problems. It takes 10 minutes for every 10K items from the moment of the request to the complete recording in the database.
Please also note that the array of clients is always changing `clients = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), new TypeToken<List<Client>>() {}.getType());` in a loop. And when its length is equal to zero, then the cycle will be interrupted. My new code above is working as expected.

However, I still have a question to which I have not found an answer. Is there still a limitation in android for a string response in the body?

Comment: My previous code, 24 hours only got a response. But I couldn't wait to receive it. In spite of the fact that the server sent the answer after 30 minutes. That is, the android client seems to be unable to read such a large string response in the body.

Comment: ***OK !!!*** The problem is you have two loops that follow the reception of the response-`String`, so you how on earth do you know if it was the "large-`String`" that is causing your delay?  Maybe those loops which are processing 150,000 `JSON Objects` are causing this giant delay.  _How can you possibly tell what is causing the hanging without checking first?_ **ALSO** The other issue I thought about was this: If you think the `String's` are too large, try printing out the `used-memory` and `available-memory`...  Use `Runtime.freeMemory()` to check available memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223993/discussion-between-y2020-09-and-dima-chibuk).